# How to access value of of input type="text" control of HTML5 in asp.net usercontrol + Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, razor, umbraco

I am using ascx page. which I am injecting in UMBRACO.

following is my .ascx Code.

```
     <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="#">
           <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" runat="server" name="name" id="txtName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required />
            </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Send Message</button>
      </form>
```

I have try to get value of text box (txtName) from back end but I am not abe to access it.

I have tried  following method to do so..(Where strtxtName is a string variable)

```
  1)  strtxtName = txtName.Value
  2) strtxtName = Request.QueryString("txtName")
  3) Request.Form.AllKeys -> return Nothing.
```

But not able to get value of text Box ,
I don't think Umbraco is making any issue.?

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using? Is it set to WebForms or MVC mode? Finally, how are you adding your ascx file to the page? As a macro, or a regular user control include, or some other method?

Comment: Tim,  I am using Umbraco 4.11.8 (WebForms), I am adding ascx as User Control

Comment: Can you post the code behind for the .ascx file? It doesn't look like you're using a server side form?